# Delivery error File too large messag file too big

Tags: osx, postfix, sendmail

I have a smarthost with Getmail+Postfix+Dovecot.

And i am receiving from some user accounts at my remote mail server this message when i am downloading to my smarthost:

```
Delivery error (command sendmail 91677 error (75, postdrop: warning: uid=501: F$
sendmail: fatal: userX_server(501): message file too big))
```

This message is the result from Sendmail that is sending mails from Getmail to Postfix, both in the same machine.

Getmail is set to download mails from my remote mail server to my smarthost.

I am able to use sendmail, but i cannot even find any path to sendmail config (searching from sendmail.cf).

This machine is using OSX 10.9.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have notice that i had several entries about this message_size_limit, in:

```
/private/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and

```
/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf
```

so i wipe those entries and did:

```
postconf -e message_size_limit=0
```

Still doing,

```
postconf -d | grep size
```

it shows,

```
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

but i have received all mails that was trapped in my remote server.

Comment: welcome to U&L, maybe you could elaborate ?

Comment: done Archemar =)

Comment: If you call `postconf -d` it will print the default parameter settings instead of actual settings. Just drop the `-d`, and you will see the changes just fine. Also, you might need to call the `postconf -e` with `sudo postconf -e ...`. And in some cases a `sudo postfix reload` helps on top of all this ;).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, you can edit the conf file so it looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 0
```

And then, you can also do `[-o name=value (override parameter value)]` like:

```
$ postconf -v -o message_size_limit=0 | grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 0
```

I think it is **not** correct to do `postconf -d | grep size` which has `[-d (parameter defaults)]` which will simply grab the default value as the argument name suggests!